# Splitting field over $K$ of a finite set of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of a finite set $\left\{ f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\right\} $
of polynomials in $K\left[x\right]$ if and only if $F$ is a splitting
field over $K$ of the single polynomial $f=f_{1}f_{2}\cdots f_{n}$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: This is a site for asking questions. If you have one, could you please edit it in?

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume your asking for a proof of the statement. If you are not, then this answer will benefit users who find this question looking for a proof.

The forward is trivial, let $f_i=g_{i1}g_{i2}g_{i3}...g_{in_j}$ be a reduction of $f_i$, then $f$ is the product of these reductions and is hence split.

The converse can be proved by induction on $n$. $n=1$ is just the same statement. If we assume $n-1$, then we may divide $f$ by the n-th polynomial. Then $f/f_n$ splits since is just some collection of factors of $f$, all of which are irreducible, and so we see $f_i$ splits for $1 \le i<n$. Now we divide $f$ by all other polynomial reductions and receive a split polynomial equal to $f_n$, thus all $f_i$ split, and the statement is proved.

**Remark:** In the future, please properly phrase the question so that people will be able to interpret what you want.